# Cloud services can't be reached from complex customer infrastructure

Tags: networking, firewall, windows-server-2012-r2

We have several services running on a cloud, they all are hosted on Windows Server 2012 R2, have public IP address and specific port.

Some of our customers can't reach them because for "some reason" the ports are cut between a firewall between them and us. (some customers are using a shared internet connection in a multi tenant office and they can't change firewall communication)

Well, you get it, we don't have the possibility to make all the firewall "allowing" the communication.

My customers all runs Windows 7 at least.

What is the best counter solution in such case, using Microsoft (Windows Server) technologies?

The best would be some kind of tunneling communication or VPN, but the customer should also be able to access his/her enterprise resources.

Bby the way, today we using IPSec using Windows Firewall to secure the communication, is IPSec tunneling a solution for us?

Otherwise, is there a service in Windows to enable some kind of VPN between a client and a server but only for a given set of servers?

Comment: If your customers can't get through their firewall to reach your services now, what makes you think their firewall would allow a VPN through? The obvious and only solution is that the customers fix their firewalls.

Comment: I'm hoping that using a VPN we'll reduce the number of different ports needed and it'll be possible to align all firewalls to enable the communication. But I agree it's not a perfect solution if the firewall can't be modified. I'm looking for a way to reduce the risk the best I can.

Comment: `I'm hoping that using a VPN we'll reduce the number of different ports needed and it'll be possible to align all firewalls to enable the communication.` - Your services run on defined ports, yes? Those ports are finite in number, yes? So there isn't a `number of different ports`, there is a finite number of defined ports. Have the customer configure their firewall to allow outbound traffic to those ports.

Comment: That's not a "complex infrastructure", that's poor customer service on the part of the ISP/building management.

Comment: Guys, I'm honestly on your side concerning the comments, but the truth is "customer is always right" and we're having hard time to explain some of them that their shared internet connection and the building IT is the root of the problem. I'm just trying to find a way to reduce the issue or the risk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best solution is to have your customers move to a firewall solution they can manage to allow access to your services.  Failing that, your next best option is to serve up your services on well-known ports that you can expect to be allowed access through virtually every firewall, which is http/https (80/443).  (Yippie, IIS.)

As pointed out in the comments, trying to engineer a VPN or IPSec solution to get around an existing firewall makes the assumption you'll be able to get a VPN or IPSec tunnel through the firewall, and I see nothing to support that assumption.

Really, at the end of the day, though, if your customers can't get through their firewall to your services, it's entirely their problem, and beyond what you can reasonably be expected to control.

Comment: Let's say IPSec Tunneling is acceptable for all the customer, would it solve my issue? If they open the set of ports we give them, all the others ports will be reachable thanks to tunneling?

Comment: @Nock Yes, if you can build an IPSec tunnel between your services and their site, that should solve the problem.  At least until their joke of a shared connection/building IT changes something, and it breaks, and then it's all your fault again.